# Firedac Visual Foxpro driver 6.0 Out of memory error in Delphi

Tags: delphi, out-of-memory, driver, visual-foxpro, firedac

Using Delphi XE8.
Connection: TFDConnection component with next params:

```
DriverID=ODBC
ODBCDriver=Microsoft FoxPro VFP Driver (*.dbf)
ODBCAdvanced=SourceDB=%s;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=No
```

where %s is replaced for a saved path.

A TFDQuery with sql='`select * from utkf`' where utkf is utkf.dbf
This table (utkf) has 4 millions of records.
The driver doesn`t accept the "select top" instruction, and then I cannot put value to the FetchOptions.RecsMax property.

How can I do for open it paged, or fetching in batch?
Only must use FireDac.

Answer (score 0):

VFP do not have an ODBC driver since VFP6. Use VFPOLEDB (OLEDB) driver instead. If you have to use ODBC driver then try Advantage Database Server (ALS local version is for free - if you ask my experience with ALS, it is not worth it. Installed, tested and removed long ago, still is an option for those who die for a local ODBC access to VFP data).

VFP ODBC driver recognizes and accepts "top" clause (however behavior might not be like in MS SQL server. It is more like TOP with Ties). Maybe it is your SQL that is wrong? VFP "TOP" requires an order by.

BTW, you can use the VFPOLEDB driver against any version of Foxpro tables.